# Version control in Cloud Firestore document

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a document containing profile information such as username and phonenumber and the user decides to change the information, is it possible to see the old value in firestore? Or do you have to keep track of such information yourself in the application ?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore does not keep track of old values for documents.  If you want to store old values, you will need to arrange for that yourself.  Consider adding new documents that describe each change, or copying the document to an archive location before making a change.